# Exception in integrating gitlab with jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a project created and configured on private Gitlab v9.0 instance. I have imported this project on Jenkins v2.46.1, the connection with gitlab is successful. Afterwards, I tried to configure build trigger on push event from repo in gitlab. I have generated secret token for it on jenkins and added a webhook with Gitlab CI URL and secret token when I tried to test the webhook it returned me below exception

```html
Hook executed successfully but returned HTTP 403 <html> <head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> <title>Error 403 anonymous is missing the Job/Build permission</title> </head> <body><h2>HTTP ERROR 403</h2> <p>Problem accessing /project/tapp-builder-service. Reason: <pre> anonymous is missing the Job/Build permission</pre></p><hr><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><hr/> </body> </html>
```

Can anyone please help me solving this?

Answer (score 5):

You can either add a special user in Jenkins for this and configure the Webhook in GitLab accordingly or you can uncheck the checkbox "Enable authentication for '/project' end-point" in the GitLab section of the global Jenkins configuration. But this should be unchecked by default.

Answer (score 5):

The best way to configure this is

1. Jenkins global configuration ->

> Require authorization for /project endpoint
>   Copy userid and API key for a Jenkins user who has authorization to run the job

2. Create a webhook on GitLab to trigger the job
3. Then use HTTP basic auth (Below format):

> http://user:apikey@gitlab/project/jobname

Comment: I don't know why this answer didn't have vote so far, but this is only working example I have tried so far

Answer (score 2):

The best option is to create a secret token (from Jenkins) and then add it to the gitlab webhook's secret key

Comment: I have created the secret token from Jenkins and included it in gitlab's Jenkins integration, but I am getting the same error. I've also tried generating a secret key in the Jenkins project I am trying to run. What else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to **save** the changes of the configuration (i.e generated secret token) on Jenkins server first before copying it to the Gitlab Webhook page

Answer (score 0):

Go to the jenkins dashboard and click the manage jenkins then click the security
in under Authentication section change Authorization  drop down to anyone can do anything

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).